# Java factory method

Tags: java

```
public interface CPR {
    double balance();
    void debit(double amount);
    void charge(double amount);
}

public class Facile implements CPR {
    private int number;

    Facile(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public double balance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void debit(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void charge(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public class Gold implements CPR {
    private int number;

    Gold(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public double balance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void debit(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void charge(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public class Ecpr implements CPR{
    private int number; 

    Ecpr(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public double balance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void debit(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void charge(double amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

achieve the following client.
Private Buisness and Puba.

- When a client is assigned the CPR, and 'created and attached to a CPR client, whose type depends on the type of customer:
  in the current policy, to a Private and 'granted an Easy Card, to a business, and' granted a Gold card to a
  component of public administration and 'assigned a card E-CPR.
- Each type of client can have its specific features: in the case of these three classes, just a business customer is entitled to
  Also make payments over the actual remaining card, the payment transaction raises for other customers
  an error (exception) in the case where the sum payable exceeds the availability 'of the paper. Of all customer types, the following methods must be available:

  1. getCPR (int number): this and 'the method that assigns to the customer, on which it' invoked, a CPR (the expected type for that type of client) the number and 'the number received;
  2. chargeCPR (double cash): Charging the card of the customer with the sum cash;
  3. payCPR (double amount) makes a payment of the total amount on the customer's card, if payment '
     possible;
  4. cancelCPR (int newnumber): Cancels the current CPR, the customer and on which 'invoked, replacing it with a new one
     CPR (of the same type) with number newnumber and on which and 'shed the legacy of the former CPR;
  5. writeInfo (): print the customer's data, namely its Tax Code, its type and is available on the client's card.

```
public abstract class Client {
    private CPR card;
    private int CF;

    Client(int CF){
        this.CF = CF;
    }

    abstract CPR makeCPR( int number);

    public void getCPR(int number){
        card = makeCPR(number);
    }

    public void chargeCPR(double amount){
        card.charge(amount);
    }

    public void payCPR(double amount) throws Exception{
    }

    public void cancelCPR(int newnumber){
    }

    public void writeInfo(){        
    }
}
```

I have difficulty in implementing other classes that extend the client.

For example, the private class I would have thought so implement it.

```
    public class Private extends Client {
    private CPR card;

    Private(int CF) {
        super(CF);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    CPR makeCPR(int number) {
        return new Facile(number);
    }

    public void payCPR(double amount) throws Exception{
        if (amount >  card.balance());
    }

    public void cancelCPR(int newnumber){
    }

    public void writeInfo(){        
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of difficulties do you have? Could you please provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need heirs of `Client` which will return a proper instance of `CPR`. To solve it you can use [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)

```
public abstract class Client<T extends CPR> {
    private CPR card;
    private int CF;

    Client(int CF){
        this.CF = CF;
    }

    abstract T makeCPR( int number);
    //....
}

public class GoldClient extends Client<Gold> {

    Gold makeCPR( int number) {
         return new Gold(number);
    }

}
```